# How to create a list with title and detail labels?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I’m trying to recreate a list view with a title label and a detail label like lots of standard iOS apps:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623273-detailtextlabel

I’d want the title label on the left, detail label on the right? Is there a standard implementation for this without building out the UI in SwiftUI?

Comment: Please share what you already have tried yourself and what part exactly is not working. Also, it is not clear from your question if you want to use SwiftUI or not.

Comment: I haven’t tried any specific implementation and can’t find any example code to even try as SwiftUI docs are sparse at the moment :)

Comment: But before SwiftUI you'd use `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` for the style of the cell.

Comment: Yeah that’s true, not sure how this would work in SwiftUI, or if we’re expected to custom build out the cell!

Comment: Have you watched *any* WWDC19 videos? Specifically, Session 204 (Introducing SwiftUI: Building Your Forst App). That is *exactly* what they show you how to do. https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/204 And in case it isn't *exactly* what you want, could you ask something more specific?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a simple view and use it like:

```
DetailedRow(title: "title", detail: "detail")
```

[image: Demo]

By encapsulating two labels and using a simple `Stack`:

```
struct DetailedRow: View {
    let title: String
    var detail: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Text(title)
            if detail?.isEmpty == false {
                Spacer()
                Text(detail).foregroundColor(Color(.secondaryLabel))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that works, have to style the detail label to match a lot of the standard UI, e.g as found as in Settings app. Just thought there may be a standard implementation of this!

Comment: Dude it is just 5 lines of code, don't be so serious. The swiftUI itself is fulls (with the IDE) of bug beside Xcode and Catalina. I think this is just the beginning and soon there will be a lot of predefined models, including these defaults ;)

Comment: Heh true! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I’ll try that a bit later! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that using an `HStack`:

```
struct ContentView : View {
  var body: some View {
    List {
      HStack {
        Text("Test")
        Spacer()
        Text("Detail")
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 16+/macOS 13.0+ you can also use the [`LabeledContent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/labeledcontent/) to do the same. It’s quite flexible and adopts to platform & context specific layouts.

> The resulting element has a layout that’s consistent with other framework controls and automatically adapts to its container, like a form or toolbar.
> – [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/labeledcontent/)

This can reach from a simple label pair like this:

```swift
LabeledContent("Title", value: "Detail“)
```

… to a more custom solution with basically any view you like:

```swift
LabeledContent {
    Button("Button") {
        // Do something
    }
} label: {
    Label("Label", systemImage: "plus")
}
```